# How do I do typeof(int) in Managed C++?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, managed

I am working on a project now and part of it uses Managed C++. In the managed C++ code, I am creating a DataTable. While defining the Columns for the datatable, I need to specify the Type of the column. In C#, that would:

typeof(int)

but how do I do that in Managed C++?

Thanks!

Comment: for future reference... if you want to see Managed Language equivalents, you can simple write the code in C#, and use Redgate Reflector to dissamble it into any CLR language.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In C++/CLI, [use the typeid keyword.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/typeid-cpp-component-extensions)

e.g.

```
Type ^t = Int32::typeid;
```

In the older "Managed C++ Extensions" syntax, you'd use `__typeof(Int32)`, but that whole version of the language is severely deprecated and you should be using C++/CLI.

Comment: Note that the keyword int is just an aliasto System.Int32

Comment: I rolled back the edit that was made, because it was wrong. In C++/CLI (as in C++) things that are contained in a type are accessed with `::` instead of `.` (as used in C#). Earlier C++/CLI compiler versions erroneously allowed the C# syntax. Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 appears to have blocked it.

Comment: In fact 2008 SP1 doesn't allow it either... why make such an edit to an answer?!

Comment: How to get for ManagedType ...typeof(ManagedClass^)