# Get .NET assembly by type in C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++

To get an assembly from a type in c# I'd use the following

```
typeof(MyTypeOrClass).Assembly
```

But how do I achieve this in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133221/how-do-i-do-typeofint-in-managed-c?

Comment: Jon, that question answers mine - I just could not find it, so thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using "typeid":

```
using namespace System;

namespace NS
{
  public ref class Foo
  {
  };
}
int main()
{
  System::Reflection::Assembly^ a = NS::Foo::typeid->Assembly;
  Console::WriteLine(a);
}
```